# Parallel array elements assignment causes crash in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, concurrency, crash

I want set elements of array concurrently,so I write code to test:

```
let Count = 1000
let SubRangeCount = 100
var ary = [Int](repeating: 0, count: Count)

let times = Count/SubRangeCount
let _ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: times){ idx in
        for i in (idx * SubRangeCount)..<((idx+1) * SubRangeCount) {
            ary[i] = Int.random(in: 0...Int.max)
        }
    }
}
```

above code working great!
But when I change like this:

```
let Count = 10000
let SubRangeCount = 1000
```

It's crash!
In playground it complain "Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range: file Swift/UnsafePointer.swift, line 832"

But you can see every range of array's assignments is NOT overlapping!

So how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Even with 1000 and 100 the code sometimes breaks.

Comment: yes!!! sometimes crash too!

Comment: Swift provides no thread safety: https://forums.swift.org/t/understanding-swifts-value-type-thread-safety/41406/6

Comment: By setting a symbolic breakpoint at `malloc_error_break`, you can see that setting Swift arrays are very much not an atomic operation, and probably accesses to some shared state as an implementation detail, which creates the race condition.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised there was no explicit "exclusive access" error.

Comment: "I want set elements of array concurrently" You can't. That's a simultaneous access to a struct and its members, and is forbidden.

Comment: refer to my answer please... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is not thread safe on Swift so you need to synchronise access to it, for instance with `objc_sync_enter` and `objc_sync_exit`:

```swift
func synchronized<T : AnyObject, U>(_ obj: T, closure: () -> U) -> U {
    objc_sync_enter(obj)
    defer {
        objc_sync_exit(obj)
    }
    return closure()
}

var arr = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 100_000)
let obj = arr as NSObject // Object to synchronise

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100_000){ index in
    synchronized(obj) {
        arr[index] = Int.random(in: 0...Int.max)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the array is concurrently mutated from multiple threads, which creates a race condition. To avoid this you have to perform the critical operation in a thread-safe way. You can take help from Grand Central Dispatch in the Apple platform - which lets us deal with threads using its much simpler queue-based abstractions.

```
let Count = 10000
let SubRangeCount = 1000
var ary = [Int](repeating: 0, count: Count)

let times = Count/SubRangeCount
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial.Queue")
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: times){ idx in
    print(idx)
    for i in (idx * SubRangeCount)..<((idx+1) * SubRangeCount) {
        serialQueue.async {
            ary[i] = Int.random(in: 0...Int.max)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use lock.

```
let Count = 10000
let SubRangeCount = 1000
var ary = [Int](repeating: 0, count: Count)
let lock = NSLock()

let times = Count/SubRangeCount
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: times){ idx in
    print(idx)
    for i in (idx * SubRangeCount)..<((idx+1) * SubRangeCount) {
        lock.lock()
        ary[i] = Int.random(in: 0...Int.max)
        lock.unlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I found a workaround for it:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: enumTimes){ idx in
    
    var subAry = ary1[(idx * SubRangeCount)..<((idx+1) * SubRangeCount)]
    
    for i in subAry.indices {
        subAry[i] = Int.random(in: 0...Int.max)
    }
}
```

It's no Crash, and fast 3x-10x than serialize assignments.

Comment: You can not change `Array` concurrently since it is not thread safe!